# How do I initialize arrays more efficiently than a for loop? c++

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

Currently, I am initializing arrays by creating for loops and setting arr[I] = 0. Is there another way to do this more efficiently?

```
Student::Student(){
    
    name = "John";
    for(int i = 0; i<sizeof(id);++i)
    {
        id[i] = '0';
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<sizeof(testScore);++i)
    {
        testScore[i] = 0;
    }
    avgScore = 100;
    grade = 'A';
    
}
```

Comment: Hi!  What programming language is this?
Please add it to the tags.

Comment: Sorry it's cpp.

Comment: memset, calloc, ...

Comment: Happy to know!
I forgot cpp... :)
Why do you need to initialize the array?
Where is it getting `id` and `testScore` from?

Comment: Do you know about [`std::fill`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill)?  Or it might be more efficient to use [`memset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset).

Comment: Thanks! memset is what I was looking for. Does it actually make the program more efficient or is it just less code?

Comment: Don't bother.  This is a microoptimization.  Print out the assembly language.  Increase the optimization level, then print out the assembly language.  Do this for all levels of optimization.

Comment: There are two optimal methods, using assembly language.  See if your processor has any specialized "fill" instructions, otherwise, you'll have to use the block memory instructions.  The other method is to see how you can use registers and the data cache with the internal parallelism of the processor.  You will probably not notice any performance improvement with such a small program.

Comment: Have you considered "loop unrolling"?  You may need a bigger, huge array, in order to have any measurable or significant increase in performance.  Search the internet for "c++ benchmarking" and "c++ profiling".

Comment: BTW, `sizeof(id)` returns the size of the entire array, in bytes, **not** the number of elements.  Use `int capacity = sizeof(id) / sizeof(id[0]);`

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Zero initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization).

example:

```cpp
    int arr1[12] = {}; // values: 000000000000
    std::array<int, 5> arr2 = {}; // values: 00000
```

This way you can skip the for loop and have a cleaner looking code.

Comment: A more efficient solution is not to initialize the array at construction; fill in the array during an input process like `std::cin`.  The Zero Initialization may end up duplicating the writing to the array.

Answer (score -1):

### Loop Unrolling

Here is an example of loop unrolling:

```
const int capacity = sizeof(id) / sizeof(id[0]);
const int fill_value = 0; // hopefully compiler assigns to a register.
int i = 0;
if (capacity & 3 == 0)
{  
    for (i = 0; i < capacity; i += 4)
    {
        id[i + 0] = fill_value;
        id[i + 1] = fill_value;
        id[i + 2] = fill_value;
        id[i + 3] = fill_value;
    }
}
// initialize remaining slots
for (; i < capacity; ++i)
{
    id[i] = 0;
}
```

The use of `fill_value` variable rather than as a constant in the loop is to suggest to the compiler of placing `fill_value` into a register.  In many processors, writing a register to memory is more efficient than either writing a constant to memory or loading the constant to register, then writing to memory (during the loop).

The idea of unrolling the loop is execute more data instructions in a row before the jump or branch instruction.  Processor's don't like branch instructions.  Branch instructions cause the processor to decide to reload the instruction cache or not; this occupies time that could be spent executing data instructions.  The unrolled loop is also performing less compares than the original loop.  Again, compare instructions occupy time that could be spent executing data instructions.

### No Looping

The goal is to minimize branching and comparing.
If your array is small (by your definition), you may want to assign the slots without a loop:

```
int * p = &id[0];
const int fill_value = 0;
*p++ = fill_value;  *p++ = fill_value; *p++ = fill_value; *p++ = fill_value;  
*p++ = fill_value;  *p++ = fill_value; *p++ = fill_value; *p++ = fill_value;  
*p++ = fill_value;  *p++ = fill_value; *p++ = fill_value; *p++ = fill_value;  
*p++ = fill_value;  *p++ = fill_value; *p++ = fill_value; *p++ = fill_value;  
*p++ = fill_value;  *p++ = fill_value; *p++ = fill_value; *p++ = fill_value;
```

The operation of incrementing the pointer and deferencing is still faster than having the processor compare a value or change the program counter (branch).